# scrollToElement function using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

> this javascript content:

```
function scrollToElement(elementSelector, instance = 0) {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(elementSelector);
  if (elements.length > instance) {
   elements[instance].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }
 }

const link1 = document.getElementById("link1");
const link2 = document.getElementById("link2");
const link3 = document.getElementById("link3");

link1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  scrollToElement(".header");
});
```

> but i not understand this and why it used instance and what tthe relation between elements.length and instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here,scrollToElement() function takes two arguments:

```
elementSelector: A CSS selector that matches the element to scroll to.
instance: The index of the element to scroll to. Defaults to 0.
```

The function first gets all the elements that match the CSS selector using the **document.querySelectorAll()** method.

Then, it checks if the **number of elements is greater than the instance** argument.

If it is, the function scrolls the **instance** element into view using the **element.scrollIntoView()** method.

The **scrollIntoView()** method takes an optional parameter called behavior which specifies how the scrolling should be animated.

In this case, you are setting it to smooth so that the scrolling is animated smoothly.

---

The **scrollToElement()** function is called when the user clicks on the **link1** element.

The **elementSelector** argument is set to **.header**, which matches the CSS selector for the header element.

The **instance** argument is set to 0, which means that the function will scroll to the first header element that it finds.

In summary, the code will scroll to the first header element on the page when the user clicks on the link1 element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified similar example (with logging instead of scrolling).

The `elementSelector` is a css query used to get the matching elements.
The `index` identifies the position of the desired element. (0 means get the first matching element, 1 means 2nd ...)

```js
function test(elementSelector, index) {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(elementSelector);
  const element = elements[index];
  if (element) console.log(element.textContent);
}

const button1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
const button2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
const button3 = document.getElementById("btn3");

button1.addEventListener("click", () => test(".text", 0)); // Get the first 
button2.addEventListener("click", () => test(".text", 1)); // Get the second
button3.addEventListener("click", () => test(".text", 2)); // Get the third
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn3">Button 3</button>

<span class="text">1st Text</span>
<span class="text">2nd Text</span>
<span class="text">3rd Text</span>
```